# How to check if variable is Scalar or Array before mxIsScalar was introduced?

Tags: c, matlab, mex

In Matlab's mex files there is a function [`mxIsScalar`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxisscalar.html) that tells you if that input to the mex files is an scalar or not. But that function has been introduced in R2015a.

If using a previous version of Matlab (2014b in my case, if that matters), what is the most elegant way of checking if an input is an Scalar or an array?

Do I need to combine `mxGetNumberOfDimensions`, `mxGetDimensions` and `mxIsNumeric` to do it? Or is there any other **clear** and **simple** way of doing it? I favor readability over speed.

Comment: I am not sure of this, but the impression is that `sizeof` could be able to do the trick. Any reason why this is not suitable here (`sizeof(vec)/sizeof(vec[0])`)?

Comment: @patrik It may do the trick. Not an experienced C code writer, so didn't know about that. I guess that is independent of what type `vec` is rigth? They'd be mxArray type in this case.

Comment: I think `sizeof` works for any type, but as I said I am not entirely sure. You can try and se if it does the trick.

Comment: There is an example at http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2014b/matlab/matlab_external/passing-a-scalar_btgcjh1-1.html which checks for scalar value. mxGetM and mxGetN should work for any type. You may want to also check for number of dimensions if you expect more than 2-D.

Comment: @Navan I cant see that example... License activation association error (although I am using a full version of Matlab in an university, so I should have any license).

Comment: Code snippet in that example is "mrows = mxGetM(prhs[0]);
ncols = mxGetN(prhs[0]);
if( !mxIsDouble(prhs[0]) || mxIsComplex(prhs[0]) ||
    !(mrows==1 && ncols==1) ) " which also is checking for complex and double.

Comment: @Navan Thanks. Consider posting that as an answer for future reference ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mrows = mxGetM(prhs[0]);
ncols = mxGetN(prhs[0]); 

if (mrows==1 && ncols==1) {
 // Scalar prhs[0] here
}
```

Note that, if prhs[0] has more than 2 dimensions say N, then mxGetN is the result of product of dimensions 2 ... N. mxGetM will always return the first dimension. This may not be a good check for sparse matrices where these may not return the actual number of elements in the matrix.

A full example mex file can be found at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-a-scalar_btgcjh1-1.html.

Answer (score 5):

As well as `mxGetM` and `mxGetN`, there's also [`mxGetNumberOfElements`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetnumberofelements.html), which you could use like so:

```
bool const isScalar = (size_t(1) == mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[0]));
```

Comment: Brilliant. While this answer is better for just scalars, the other one can check for any dimension so I feel its more complete. However very very nice for the case of only scalars/non scalar!

Comment: @AnderBiguri I'd argue that this answer is more appropriate for just checking for scalars (without `mxIsScalar` that is).  Consider a `m-by-n-by-p` array.  [`mxGetN`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetn.html) would report `n*p`, not very clear.  Using `mxGetNumberOfElements` does not confuse the issue.